# Сложный запрос. Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
  CREATE TABLE company (
  id integer NOT NULL,
  name character varying,
  CONSTRAINT company_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id));

  CREATE TABLE person (
  id integer NOT NULL,
  name character varying,
  company_id integer,
  CONSTRAINT person_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

Есть две таблицы. Нужно:
Select the name of the company with the maximum number of persons + number of persons in this company.

Upd. Разобрался, решил.

Comment: И что именно у вас не получилось с этой простейшей учебной задачей?

Comment: Если конкретно, то не получилось ее решить. Это не вся задача, а лишь последний пункт, до этого порешал, а тут встрял. Sql изучаю сравнительно недавно, пару дней назад узнал про джойны, а тут запрос посложнее наверное. Уже пару дней как бьюсь и все бестолку.

Comment: Вы покажите, как именно вы бьетесь. Какой результат получаете и какой должен получиться

Comment: select person.name, company.name from person
 left outer join company on person.company_id = company.id; так я получаю всех юзеров и их компании, а мне нужно как то посчитать сколько юзеров в каждой компании, и именно подсчет этот сбивает с толку

Comment: почитайте про group by

Comment: вся сложность в том, что нужно запрос делать к двум таблицам, а не к одной. Я могу получить количество персон для каждой компании, но когда пытаюсь получить еще и имя компании, получается каша.

Answer (score 0):

Название компании с максимальным числом сотрудников и число сотрудников

```
select c.name , count(*)
from company с inner join person p on c.id = p.company_id
group by c.name order by count(*) desc limit 1;
```